Wrong pricing tier for Open AI TextAnalytics
I'm trying to use the Azure Open AI TextAnalyticsClient, specifically the AbstractiveSummary. I've set up an Open AI Service in the East US region with the S0 pricing plan. I've grabbed the Endpoint and the key for the service and create the client like this:
TextAnalyticsClient tac = new TextAnalyticsClient(
    new Uri("https://???open ai service???.openai.azure.com/"),
    new AzureKeyCredential("???key???"));
            

However, when I try to call the AbstractiveSummarize method with this code (sensitive information removed):
 AbstractiveSummarizeOperation aso = tac.AbstractiveSummarize(WaitUntil.Completed, docs);

I get this message:

The Submit text analysis job Operation under Microsoft Cognitive
Language Service - 2023-04-01 is not supported with the current
subscription key and pricing tier OpenAI.S0

That S0 at the end looks like the pricing plan I've selected. I have a Visual Enterprise and a Pay-As-You-Go subscription and, under both plans, the only pricing tier I can pick is the S0 plan.
What am I missing here?

Did you grant access to the Language service by assigning the "Cognitive Services Language Reader" role to your service principal.

I had not...but, sadly, this doesn't seem to have fixed my problem: I'm still getting the wrong pricing tier message. Perhaps, I'm doing it wrong? I created a system identity for my Open AI Service and assigned it the Language Reader role. Should I have my app claim an App Registration? I'd be more comfortable if the message was permission-oriented rather than subscription oriented, though.


I'm trying to use the Azure Open AI TextAnalyticsClient, specifically
the AbstractiveSummary.

The above query is solved in MS-Q&A by AshokPeddakotla-MSFT.
Posting it an answer so that it will help community to find better solution.

The Submit text analysis job Operation under Microsoft Cognitive Language Service - 2023-04-01 is not supported with the current subscription key and pricing tier OpenAI.S0


The above error occur due to TextAnalyticsClient from the azure openai service which doesn't support AbstractiveSummarize feature.
The  AbstractiveSummarize feature is part of the Language service under Azure Cognitive Services.

So, ensure that you are creating a Language resource in Cognitive Services and using that endpoint and key.
Reference:
Quickstart: Use Summarization - Azure AI services | Microsoft Learn
